# Url redirection without registering redirection url in global.asax MVC3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have  redirection URL like "https://www.syncfusion.com/msdn" . if we entered this URL in browser, it goes to "https://www.syncfusion.com/home/aboutus?utm_medium=msdn".

For this URL Redirection , created Route map in global.asax file "

```
 routes.MapRouteLowercase(
      "MSDN", // Route name
      "newsletter", // URL with parameters
      new { Controller = "root", Action = "Redirection", key = "msdn" } 
     // Parameter defaults
 );
```

here i created seperate action to handle URL redirection.

So my request without registering Redirection URL in Global and without seperate action can we have redirecting URL to specified URL?.

Comment: So you want to do a redirect without actually specifying any redirects anywhere??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller itself you can do the same.

```
   return  RedirectToAction("Redirection", "root",new{key="msdn"})
```

If you are redirecting to an existing url, then you can try

```
return Redirect(redirecturl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating a custom redirect route and handlers(IRouteHandler/IHttpHandler) as specified at the end of this blog [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/7/understanding_routing).